# Saving images from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R and trying to use the below code for cropping and saving multiple files in a R loop. It works fine, but the only problem is that as it saves the output images, the same output file gets overwritten resulting in only the last image being saved. I would like to have the cropped images saved as separate files as 'trial_1.png', 'trial_2.png', etc. I can't figure out how to fix this any any suggestions regarding this would be welcome. The code mainly uses the magick package functions. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
library(pdftools)
library(magick)
library(png)
library(raster)

path = "~/Desktop/RME_task"
file.names<-dir(path, pattern = ".png") 
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){

rme_stimuli_set1_1<-image_read(file.names[i])
rme_stimuli_set1_1_scaled<-image_scale(rme_stimuli_set1_1, "700x700")
rme_stimuli_set1_1_cropped<-image_crop(rme_stimuli_set1_1_scaled, "305x120+118+322")
image_write(rme_stimuli_set1_1_cropped, "CROPPED/trial_.png")

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change the file name in each interaction.

```
library(pdftools)
library(magick)
library(png)
library(raster)

path = "~/Desktop/RME_task"
file.names<-dir(path, pattern = ".png") 
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){

rme_stimuli_set1_1<-image_read(file.names[i])
rme_stimuli_set1_1_scaled<-image_scale(rme_stimuli_set1_1, "700x700")
rme_stimuli_set1_1_cropped<-image_crop(rme_stimuli_set1_1_scaled, "305x120+118+322")
image_write(rme_stimuli_set1_1_cropped, paste0("CROPPED/trial_",i,".png"))

}
```

in this way each interaction of the loop will create trial_1.png, trial_2.png, etc.